# Just in Time SSO

Tags: single-sign-on

We are implementing a Just in Time Federated SSO for which we are sending full base64 encoded SAML response
under which we have all the data elements in Pass through data.

Can salesforce parse that and extract each individual elements, if yes, do we need to follow some specific steps to achieve this?

How the Identity Provider would be mapping/aware of Account Id and Contact ID for the user?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Sara, are you trying to create users in Salesforce on the fly, using [Just-in-Time provisioning](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_jit_about.htm&language=en_US)? If so, have you tried specifying the `User.ContactId` attribute in your assertion?

I think if you add an attribute (example below) based on Salesforce's [sample assertion](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_saml_assertion_examples.htm&language=en_US), the users created by Just-in-Time provisioning will be associated to the correct contact, and by association to the correct account.

```
<saml:Attribute Name="User.ContactId"
    NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
    <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:anyType">003o0000002rYsN
    </saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
```

Comment: Hi @Marty, that is true we are creating user using JIT and ur answer did help, but the main question is We are implementing a Just in Time Federated SSO for which we are sending full base64 encoded SAML response under which we have all the data elements in Pass through data.

Can salesforce parse that and extract each individual elements, if yes, do we need to follow some specific steps to achieve this?

Comment: Hi, @Sara, I'm sorry for the lack of understanding, but I'm not sure I follow what you mean by "pass-through data". Can you explain a bit more what you mean by that? And maybe post a sample SAML response from your process?